# Bounding summation by an integral

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Let $f$ be a positive real-valued function. I know that if $f$ is non-increasing, then
$$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)\leq\int_{1}^{x}f(x)dx+f(1)$$
and if $f$ is non-decreasing, then
$$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)\leq\int_{1}^{x}f(x)dx+f(x).$$

For general positive real-valued function $f$, how to bound the summation $\displaystyle\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)$ by integral?

Comment: You can draw some simple pictures to see that this cannot be done in full generality.  You need some conditions like the ones you stated.

Comment: $f(n)\le max_{x=n}^{n+1}f(x)$ is all you can use.

Comment: You can bound it separately on intervals where $f$ is increasing or decreasing.